# input username and password and buttons

Tags: button, passwords

on php or html page how can i do this:

name 
password 
and many buttons

if user press button1 he we redirct to :

http://domain.com/login.php?button1=123&name=test&password=111

buttom2:
http://domain.com/login.php?button2=456&name=test&password=111

buttom3:
http://domain.com/login.php?button3=789&name=test&password=111

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have this simple option according to me.

   <form action='login.php' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='name'>
    <input type='password' name='password'>
    <input type='submit' name='button1' value='123'>
    <input type='submit' name='button2' value='456'>
    <input type='submit' name='button2' value='789'>
   </form>


Hope it helps
```

Comment: thank you for answer , but by this way i cant set name for each the button as: 
button1 name is welcome  link is :

http://domain.com/login.php?button1=123&name=test&password=111

its now :
http://domain.com/login.php?welcome=123&name=test&password=111

Comment: brother first plz upvote if u like answers :)

wat is the issue i think the concept of form is not clear to u.

To change the button1=123 to welcome=123 you can simply change the name parameter of "button1" to "welcome" . To understand better just copy the above reply code to file and just name it with extension .html now open this file in browser and play change parameters and see how it works...